# First digit of $3^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$3^n$ begins with 1 for some non negative integers $n$ Find the number of such integers $n$ where $0\leq n\leq 1000$   Example $3^0=1,3^9=19683$
  We can write number in the form $a_0+10a_1+\dots+10^ma_m$ the coefficient $a_m$ should be $1$.          Is it right approach to solve?

Comment: Benford's law says that about if a sequence follows an exponential distribution,  $30\%$  (that is $\log 2- \log 1$) will have a leading digit of $1$

Comment: @DougM That's a good approximator for large $n$, but how do you provide an exact value for $n = 1000$? (It turns out that $300$ is exactly correct, but how do you prove it?)

Comment: @orlp The expectation is 301.  And, I would think that it would be very close to that.  If you consider the cyclic group of integers $\mathbb Z_{1000}$, and consider $n\cdot 477\pmod {1000}$  (i.e. $\log 3 \approx 0.477$) over $1000$ choices of $n$ you will cycle through every element in the group.  Now $\log 3$ does not exactly equal $0.477$ so there will be small errors.  (Still not quite a proof, but giving a pretty clear indication)

Comment: @DougM It would be very close, but unless the exercise asks for a number that's 'pretty close', it doesn't exactly get you anywhere, without some trick to make the bound tight.

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is just to compute them.  If you have an arbitrary precision system, you can get the largest power of $10$ less than $3^n$ by taking the floor of $\log_{10}(3^n)$.  Call it $k$.  The first digit of $3^n$ is $\left\lfloor \frac {3^n}{10^k}\right\rfloor$  Unfortunately $3^n$ will overflow if you use normal computer numbers.

The solution is to use the logarithm.  $\log_{10}3^n=n\log_{10}3$.  If the fractional part of this is between $0$ and $\log_{10}2$, the first digit is $1$.  The integer part will be the $k$ from above, and we will have $10^k \lt 3^n \lt 2\cdot 10^k$

Comment: _"Unfortunately $3^n$ will overflow if you use normal computer numbers."_ That depends entirely on your programming language's definition of a number. In Python $3^n$ will not overflow. E.g. `len([n for n in range(1, 1001) if str(3**n)[0] == "1"])`.

Comment: @orlp:  that was precisely my point in the second sentence.  Python has arbitrary precision integers, as do Mathematica and Matlab.  There are others.  I was using the log to strip off the first digit instead of converting to a string. In Python I suspect  you need the string because only integers are arbitrary precision.